# Remove / and .php/html from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php

Well, the title says pretty much all of it, I want to remove the slash and the extenstion from PHP_SELF, is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: `str_replace()`. Or `explode()`.

Comment: You should not use `PHP_SELF`, it is very manipulatable.

Comment: @Martijn I don't think it will be a problem the way I'm using it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php'); //or replace .php with .html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```